# Permission in shell but not from spawned program even though user and group are the same?

Tags: linux, permissions

I have user and group test:test

When I'm at the shell logged in as test I can do `git pull origin master` and `npm install` and it works.

I also have a cgi script that gets called from Caddy (a webserver). It does the same thing *as the same user* but yet it gets permission errors.

How do I debug this. What commands will show me why I'm getting permission when in the shell but not when running from a spawned script?

The errors in the script are

```
Could not create directory '/home/test/.ssh'.
```

`/home/test/.ssh` already exists and already has keys etc. They work fine from the shell

for npm it gets these errors

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-87-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /home/test/.npm/_locks
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/test/.npm/_locks'
```

But yet again, running from the shell no errors.

I added `id` to the script so I could see what user the script is running as. It prints

```
uid=1000(test) gid=1000(test) groups=1000(test),27(sudo)
```

Which is the exact same thing it prints when I type `id` in the shell

What else should I be looking for?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was caddy is run from systemd and it was set to

```
ProtectHome=true
```

which means `/home/test` is off limits to the spawned script. Not sure what the correct solution is but at least tracked down the source of the issue